# Remove Duplicates while doing Distinct

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three columns A,B and C. 
This is my table

I am trying to group by A,B and do a distinct of C

[image]

when i run the query,

select A,B,Distinct(c)
from table
group by A,B
having count(C)>1

this gives me the output

[image]

I want to remove the nulls from C and see the following output
[image]

Comment: Your query and output don't match up properly, because none of the groups shown have a `COUNT(C)` which is greater than 1.

Comment: `select A,B,Distinct(c)` is not valid SQL Syntax.

Comment: Please provide the tables in words, not in image.

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function. This query would produce nothing other than a syntax error.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Use edit functions to inline, not links, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained. Replace a link to a table by code block formatted tabular text--which in a code question should simultaneously be code to create & initialize a table since the question should give a [mcve]. PS Read the edit help re code block format.

Comment: Hi. "group by A,B and do a distinct of C" is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & descriptions to clearly say what you mean. Refer to examples, including examples of intermediate expressions.

Answer (score 2):

You may `COUNT` the column `C` directly if you want to ignore `NULL` values:

```
SELECT A, B, COUNT(C) AS cnt
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY A, B;
```

### Demo

The `COUNT` function by default will ignore `NULL` when counting, so the above query should generate the following output:

```
A | B | cnt
x | y | 1
u | v | 1
```

If you want to get the total number of records per group, which is what your current output is showing, then use `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(C)`.

Comment: i tried count and it sill shows the same value. Is there anyway to create a sub query to remove the nulls and then do a group by ?

Comment: @RifadhZizou You didn't run my query with your data, because the query should be working, q.v. [this demo](https://rextester.com/BGSW51488).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen. . . I think op has confused about the distinct with `count()`. So, i would just do `COUNT(DISTINCT C)` that might be reflect in numbers.

Comment: @YogeshSharma Interesting suggestion, but that wouldn't actually change the expected output, at least not using the sample data in the OP.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen. . . I suggested this because of `distinct` used with op query.